# Get a PHP Parse error. But where is the error?

Tags: php

My code runs perfectly on localhost.. 
But when I sent it to web, I get this error:

PHP Parse error:  parse error in E:\home\site\Web\sw\class\sql.php on line 60

Here is the line 60:

```
        if($caractere) {


            $code = preg_replace_callback(
               "/(SW_(\w+))/",
               function($matches) use ($line) { //THIS IS THE LINE 60

                    return utf8_encode($line[$matches[2]]);
               },
               $codigoHtmlDeRetorno
            );
            echo $codigo;

        }
```

I really can't understand!
Where is the fault?

Comment: Your sever runs on  PHP <5.3, means it doesn't support anonymous functions. Your server either runs with 4.2.2/3/4 and PHP 4 is already dead forever. (Do: `echo PHP_VERSION;` to see the version)

Comment: BTW: PHP 4.3.3 is from 2002, which is over 14 years ago, you definitely need to upgrade your server.